# VSCode extensions have golang.go, but haven't ms-vscode.go

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed the vscode to dev go app.

When I search extensions, I cannot find a go extension by ms.

But I found there is a golang version.

Is go extension made by ms is replaced by a version made by golang?

[image: VScode doesn't have a ms-vscode.go extension]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft just transferred the support/ownership of vscode-go to Google's Go team. If you search for `golang` in extensions you'll the "Go" extension by "Go Team at Google" - that's the same old extension as before.

From the Go blog: http://blog.golang.com/vscode-go

Comment: Thank you for your perfectly answering my question, which bothered me a lot.